# Bootstrap Two Column Layout Misalignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple two column layout which has one big image followed by two columns, left one for image right one for text.

[image: Misalignment]

But I'm not able to align the image column with the top big image.
I can add a class with -15px margin but then there is misalignment in XS screen size.

[image: with -15px margin]

I can add another -15px margin for xs screen also then I might have to fix something else. This is such a basic layout issue, I have a feeling I am doing something wrong.

Can you guys suggest what I am doing wrong and how should I approach two column layout in Bootstrap 3?

Here is the [Bootply Link](https://www.bootply.com/JEtvQVy5zE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<div class="col-sm-12">` in the lower box causes the trouble. You have two options here:

1. Just delete the div
2. Add an additional `<div class="row">` after the `<div class="col-sm-12">`

You were essentially creating a nested grid and bootstrap requires you to begin every new nesting level with a new `<div class="row">`

See: http://www.bootply.com/sh13QtYpFP

Comment: Tried it, it resolved the issue. Thanks you very much! :)

I am using the option 2. 
Curious to know which option is ideal? 1 or 2?

Comment: For your specific use case, option 1 would have been sufficient, as it is cleaner HTML with less clutter.

Comment: Option 2 would be useful when you plan to add additional sub-columns and a deeper nesting level.

Answer (score 1):

@bspellmeyer is correct. When nesting columns in Bootstrap, you need to add a `row` and then your nested columns.

**HERE IS WHY**

The grid works with 3 parts: a container, a row and column(s)...

The container has 15px of padding. The row negates the container padding with -15px of margin. Columns have 15px of padding, which pull the content away from the edges of the container and create a consistent 30px gutter.

The purpose for adding 15px of padding that is only negated by the negative row margins seems silly, but it is essential to allow for nesting columns inside of other columns! Note in the diagram below how the nested columns indicated by the red outline fits neatly into the enclosing column without getting additional padding applied.

[image: TBS Grid]

I promise that once this sinks in, making the grid behave exactly how you want every time will be a breeze.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add :

```
.custom-left {    
    padding: 0;
}
```

to your **.custom-left** class. Add the same to your .custom-right class if you want to align this div with the top image as well.

**Updated Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/iQYEpYqXJZ**

Comment: Huh? Who voted the answer down? Did you even look at the updated Bootply?